# Buscar registos com Data mais recente Usando condicao

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT 
    fm.FIELDCODE, 
    fm.BLOCK_CODE, 
    bl.BLOCK_DESC, 
    cat.CATEGORY_CODE, 
    cat.CATEGORY_ABBREV, 
    fm.FIELD_AREA, 
    fm.PLANTATION_DATE, 
    fm.HARVEST_END_DATE 

FROM 
    FM_BLOCK bl, 
    FM_FIELD_CATEGORY cat, 
    FM_FIELDMASTER_DETAIL fm  
WHERE 
    fm.PLANTATION_DATE = (  
        SELECT MAX(fm.PLANTATION_DATE) 
            FROM FM_FIELDMASTER_DETAIL fm where fm.FIELDCODE = '102'
    )
    and fm.BLOCK_CODE = bl.BLOCK_CODE
    and fm.DPTCOD = bl.DPTCOD 
    and fm.CATEGORY_CODE = cat.CATEGORY_CODE 
    and fm.FIELDCODE = '102'
```

Como faço a consulta para me retornar o `FIELDCODE` com `PLANTATION_DATE` mais recente caso a coluna `HARVEST_END DATE` nao tenha valor, caso a coluna `HARVEST_END_DATE` tenha registo me retorne `FIELDCODE` com `HARVEST_END_DATE` mais recente como faço, alguma sugestao??? pois a minha consulta só me traz o `FIELDCODE` com `PLANTATION_DATE` mais recente.

Comment: PLANTATION_DATE ou HARVEST_END DATE    @Kennel Rafael ?

Comment: Amigo, qual banco é a consulta? E tem como você simplificar a sua dúvida? Ta muito confusa..

Comment: Já deu uma olhada em como funciona o `case when`?

Comment: Sim ja, Agora funciona com o decode

Answer (score 1):

Coalesce pode resolver:

```
SELECT 
 fm.FIELDCODE, 
 fm.BLOCK_CODE, 
 bl.BLOCK_DESC, 
 cat.CATEGORY_CODE, 
 cat.CATEGORY_ABBREV, 
 fm.FIELD_AREA, 
 fm.PLANTATION_DATE, 
 fm.HARVEST_END_DATE 
FROM 
 FM_BLOCK bl, 
 FM_FIELD_CATEGORY cat, 
 FM_FIELDMASTER_DETAIL fm  
WHERE 
 fm.PLANTATION_DATE = (  
    SELECT MAX(coalesce(fm2.HARVEST_END_DATE, fm2.PLANTATION_DATE))
        FROM FM_FIELDMASTER_DETAIL fm2 where fm2.FIELDCODE = '102'
 )
 and fm.BLOCK_CODE = bl.BLOCK_CODE
 and fm.DPTCOD = bl.DPTCOD 
 and fm.CATEGORY_CODE = cat.CATEGORY_CODE 
 and fm.FIELDCODE = '102'
```

Comment: Esse tambem funciona perfeitamente, muito obrigado pelas respostas, resolveram o meu problema